# how to set color and grid in areaplot using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>areaplot</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style> 
            svg { border: 1px solid #dedede; }

            .axis path, .axis line {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #000;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .area { fill: skyblue; }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="area" />
        <script>
            d3.csv("performance.csv", function (error, data) {

                data.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.stocks = +d.stocks;
                });
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
                width = 575 - margin.left - margin.right,
                        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                var x = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
                                return d.percentage;
                            }), d3.min(data, function (d) {
                                return d.percentage;
                            })])
                        .range([0, width]);

                var y = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                                return d.stocks;
                            })])
                        .range([height, 0]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(x)
                        .orient("bottom");

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(y)
                        .orient("left");
                var area = d3.svg.area()
                        .x(function (d) {
                            return x(d.percentage);
                        })
                        .y0(height)
                        .y1(function (d) {
                            return y(d.stocks);
                        });
                var svg = d3.select("svg#area")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                svg.append("path")
                        .datum(data)
                        .attr("class", "area")
                        .attr("d", area);

                svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                        .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .call(yAxis);

            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have to set the grid and the colors to look the same as in this picture:

[image: areaplot pic]

My CSV file contains the following data:

```
stocks,percentage
400,100
300,75
200,70
100,50
75,20
```

How do I add the grid and set the colors using d3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using linear gradient.

```
  var gradient = d3.select("svg").append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
  //start color white
  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "white")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
  //end color steel blue
  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "90%")
    .attr("stop-color", "steelblue")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

On the area path:

```
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .style("fill", "url(#gradient)")//set the fill to the gradient id created above.
    .attr("d", area);
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbV2eikcLbA9r5eWamBI?p=preview)

Comment: ya thank you..i have to add grid x andy axis same as above picture

Comment: sry i cant make it exact but here is my try http://plnkr.co/edit/NbV2eikcLbA9r5eWamBI?p=preview